# Animate an animation cancel

Tags: android

Say I'm animating a button from `x=0` to `x=200`, using:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "x", 0f, 200f);
animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animator.start();
```

Now, when the button is at `x=100`, I want to cancel the animation. When I call `animator.cancel()`, the button stops abruptly. What I'm trying to achieve is that the `x` value gradually slows down (somewhat like a `DecelerateInterpolator`), and neatly comes to a stop at, say, `x=120`.

Ofcourse, I could just `cancel()` the animation and start a new decelerating animator. However, this does not take the current velocity of the button in account, leading to weird behavior.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by @Gil, You have to deal with your custom `Interpolator` implementation. The good news is that you don't actually need to implement everything yourself. You can just combine 2 different interpolation formulas: accelerate/decelerate for the main animation and decelerate interpolator for cancellation.

Essentially that's what you are looking for:

Normal accelerate/decelerate animation:
[image]

Your animation when you cancel it somewhere in the middle:
[image]

Here is my quick interpolator implementation:

```
static class MyInterpolator extends AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator {

    private float phaseShift = 0f;
    private boolean isCancelled = false;
    private float lastInput = 0f;

    /**
     * Maps a value representing the elapsed fraction of an animation to a value that represents
     * the interpolated fraction. This interpolated value is then multiplied by the change in
     * value of an animation to derive the animated value at the current elapsed animation time.
     *
     * @param input A value between 0 and 1.0 indicating our current point
     *              in the animation where 0 represents the start and 1.0 represents
     *              the end
     * @return The interpolation value. This value can be more than 1.0 for
     * interpolators which overshoot their targets, or less than 0 for
     * interpolators that undershoot their targets.
     */
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        lastInput = input;
        if(!isCancelled)
        {
            return super.getInterpolation(input);
        }
        else
        {
            return getCancellationInterpolation(input) - phaseShift;
        }
    }

    public void cancel()
    {
        isCancelled = true;
        this.phaseShift = getCancellationInterpolation(lastInput) - super.getInterpolation(lastInput);

    }

    private float getCancellationInterpolation(float input)
    {
        return (1.0f - (1.0f - input) * (1.0f - input));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use default interpolation for normal animation and switch do deceleration one when animation is canceled. Obviously this code is not perfect (it doesn't reset `phaseShift` value and `isCancelled` flag which causes miscalculation if you use repeat mode), but that's something you hopefully can figure out yourself :)

I created sample project [on GitHub](https://github.com/paveldudka/SmartAnimationCancellation), so you can see how it looks like

**FOLLOW UP**
I played a bit more with formulas and taken the second part of `DecelerateInterpolator` implementation. I introduced `factor` parameter which helps you to control how fast your cancellation should happen (some sort of traction). Setting `factor` to `1.5` gives me this:
[image]

As you can see, when I hit `cancel` at ~0.5 point, animation gets cancelled more quickly (so it doesn't go all the way to the 0.7 of the distance as in previous example). It gives a bit better feeling of real object. Higher `factor` - faster your animation will stop.

Here is an updated interpolator:

```
static class MyInterpolator extends AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator {

    ......
    private float factor = 1.5f;
    .......

    private float getCancellationInterpolation(float input)
    {
        if(factor == 1)
        {
            return (1.0f - (1.0f - input) * (1.0f - input));
        }
        else
        {
            return (float)(1.0f - Math.pow((1.0f - input), 2 * factor));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, I meant something on those lines. How did you come up with the formula in `getCancellationInterpolation(float)`? The graphs look rather linear, but it is a matter of taste. Anyway, if it is not already, you could take this one step further and use  `DecelerateInterpolator.getInterpolation(float)` as Niek hinted.

Comment: @Gil formula is taken from `DecelerateInterpolator` source code :)

Comment: This looks really good! Amazing answer. Could you perhaps elaborate on the `phaseShift` value?

Answer (score 1):

You run your animation all the way through and you implement your [TimeInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html) that "slows down" after accelerating.

You need to implement the method `getInterpolation(float)`: this represents a mathematical function that maps time instants to your position values x normalised between 0 and 1. For instance, if you wanna run from `x = 0` to `x = 120`, the value `x = 100` corresponds to the normalised value

> 100/|120 - 0| = 0.83

Finding the right function requires some mathematical sophistication and some guessing, but this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#interpolators) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I was secretly hoping there existed some magical way to do this, but alas, I guess I'll need to dive in the interpolators myself.

Comment: By the way, most of the time I just want to animate from `0` to `200`, but sometimes I want to cancel the animation at some arbitrary value, and would like it to gracefully stop. Interrupting the running animation and continuing with a new shorter decelerating animation is the hardest part.

Comment: Pavel's code should help. I'll briefly comment his code too for some additional feedback